Force RichEdit 4.1 in Delphi 12 Athens?
When checking the RichEdit version of an existing TRichEdit instance in Delphi 12.1 in Windows 11, I always get version 2.0 (where it should be version 4.1 or later):
function GetRichEditVersion(RichEditHandle: HWND): string;
var
  ClassName: array[0..255] of Char;
begin
  if GetClassName(RichEditHandle, ClassName, Length(ClassName)) > 0 then
  begin
    if StrPos(ClassName, 'RICHEDIT50W') <> nil then
      Result := 'RichEdit 4.1'
    else if StrPos(ClassName, 'RichEdit20W') <> nil then
      Result := 'RichEdit 3.0'
    else if StrPos(ClassName, 'RichEdit') <> nil then
      Result := 'RichEdit 2.0'
    else
      Result := 'RichEdit 1.0 or older';
  end
  else
    Result := 'Unable to determine RichEdit version';
end;

This is the RichEdit history:
• RichEdit 1.0: The first version, very basic, supports only ANSI text.
• RichEdit 2.0: Introduced with Windows 95, supports Unicode.
• RichEdit 3.0: Introduced in Windows 2000/XP, added more features such as better font handling.
• RichEdit 4.0 and later: RichEdit 4.1 is included with Windows Vista and later, with advanced features such as zoom support (which is what TRichEdit in modern Delphi versions typically wraps).

You apparently haven't checked what GetClassName really puts in ClassName. The class name of a TRichEdit control is always TRichEdit, so you cannot use this approach to determine the actual version. (Of course, your GetRichEditVersion will always return 2.0.)

The VCL uses subclassed window classes (see TWinControl.CreateSubClass(), which most windowed controls use internally). As such, you can't use GetClassName() in this manner, as it will not report the original class name, but rather it will report the subclass name - in this case, 'TRichEdit', which is why your code always returns 2.0.  If you weren't using StrPos() (which is the wrong comparison for this task, BTW), then your code would be returning 1.0 instead.
Try using RealGetWindowClass() instead. See:

What's the difference between RealGetWindowClass and GetClassName? (or what is a "Window type" versus a "Window class name"?)

What makes RealGetWindowClass so much more real than GetClassName?


FYI, TRichEdit has been using Rich Edit 4.1 (RICHEDIT50W) since 11.0 Alexandria:

TRichEdit Component updated to RichEdit 4.1 (MSFTEDIT.dll)

